# Multiple Sections on One Webpage

Tags: php

I'm a total programming beginner trying to absorb  HTML, PHP and MYSQL. This is my first question.

I plan to build a site that has an "admin" part and a registered user/member section that are displayed at the same time.

To give a better picture,  think of YELP where there is the a part for the business-establishment's section on top and the reviews on the lower section. The difference is that the business owner/admin can access/edit the business section but will NOT be able to do so on the review part; vice-versa for the review/member-user on the bottom.

How should I plan to do the layout? WIll they be put together with two different PHP code under one html page?

Could someone please provide a layout-structure as guidance?

Example

```
<html>
<?php
include( businessowner_admin.php); //with all the validations etc.

inlude(registered_member.php); //with all the validations etc.

?> 
</html>
```

Am I on the right path? Or is CSS needed to handle this?

Thanks
Katy

Comment: First off, I find it very rude for someone to vote down a question on a new user unless that user has blatantly misused this site.  Second off, That certainly is a way to do it.  Ever heard of the saying "There's 9 ways to skin a cat"? Well, that's one of them.  Since you're beginning you need to start coding to what you are comfortable.  Then you will learn more and more.  Eventually you will rewrite anything you care about anyways.

Comment: Oh, and learn how to layout what you want with HTML before you add the PHP.  Start even before that and draw it on paper

Comment: Thanks so much for the first response, ntgCleaner. I was beggining to get discouraged when I saw the -1. I thought this was a site to learn; I guess those that have real expertise and desire to impart knowledge prevail in the end :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[preach mode on]

I think you're following the wrong way. It's generally a bad idea to have two almost completely unrelated set of functionality on a single page. And, an overall problem with PHP is that it makes incredibly easy to follow bad coding standards.

So, instead of providing you a good layout so you could toss in bad code (don't get it offensive, step one in every programmer's development - write bad code :))

1. Study PHP the [right way](http://www.phptherightway.com/)
2. Invest some amount of time into studying some well-known well-designed PHP [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) frameworks (e.g. [Symfony](http://symfony.com/), [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/) or [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/)).
3. Learn HTML and CSS (google for CSS or HTML tutorial - tons of them).
4. Get aquinted with some good text editor like [Sublime Text2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) or [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (hardcore programmers will recommend `vim` or `emacs` - don't listen to them *yet*. Those are powerful beasts, but require huge amount of effort to learn and, hm... adopt them :))
5. Learn some database basics (if you're not sure - start with [MySql](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)) and how to couple it with PHP (**never use mysql_[something]** PHP functions - they are deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `pdo` first, than move to some `ORM` frameworks, like [Doctrine2](http://www.doctrine-project.org/)).
6. Finally, learn javascript (e.g. on [codeacademy](http://www.codecademy.com)) and some good javascript framework ([jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is de-facto "standard").

All those mentioned instruments and techniques are free of charge, so the only resource required is your time, not money.

Move one step at a time. This path, walked the proper way, should not take less than a couple of months. But at the end you're going to be skilled wed-developer, suitable for the majority of the tasks.

[preach mode off]

As for the question, you'd better separate the "admin" and "frontend" pages, so you could manage access, content and styling easier. So, you could use some common parts, like header/footer, menu, etc. as an includes on those pages, but the pages itself better be separate in my opinion (and still, you'd better learn and use some

Comment: WOW! Now if that isn't a clear path for a beginner, I don't know what is. Thanks, JOHN! I'll take your suggestions to heart. I'm excited to learn!

Comment: You're welcome. I wish someone told me something like this when I was a beginner :) Could have saved me a year or two :) Also, as a cherry for the pie, check out udacity's [Web Development](https://www.udacity.com/course/cs253) course. It's tought using python, not PHP, but (1) the concepts are the same, (2) python is as good as php (if not better) and I like python more than php :)

Comment: @JOHN: It looks like your post was cut off at "and use some ...". Did you mean to add something? When you say "separate pages", do you mean that I cannot have them viewed at the same time (of course like I said, business-admin can edit their section but not members and vice versa)?

Comment: No, it was just a dangling phrase. Separate page - means that admin section should be on separate, distinct page and members should not be able to access it at all.